# Javascript: does not work when combine JQuery click with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create a clickable table but when I add setInterval to reload this table in every 1000, the click event will stop working. Here is the code:

JQuery & Javascript parts:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Set the timer 
    var myTimer = setInterval(function(){showTableContent(),1000});

    //Add click 
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var idForTableRowInfor = "#" + $("div div div table").attr('id');
       $(idForTableRowInfor).click(function () {
           alert('row was clicked');
        });
    })

    //Function of showTableContent()
    function showTableContent() 
    {
      var body = plugin().USBInforArray; //Call FireBreath plugin
      document.getElementById('tableInfor').innerHTML = body;
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

HTML parts:

```
...   
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div id="USBDetectingTable" align="center">
           <table id="tableInfor" border="1">
           </table>
        </div> ...
```

When I get rid of setInterval everything works fine, but as long as I add into that function, it stops calling click event. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){showTableContent(),1000});
```

should be

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){showTableContent()},1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

The click no longer works because you are removing the rows and the click is no longer attached.

Learn about the power of [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#tableInfor").on("click", idForTableRowInfor, function () {
       alert('row was clicked');
});
```

Comment: And the other one got the selected answer? yikes.